# How to cherry-pick bootstrap-vue.js modules in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am not able to understand how to cherry-pick bootstrap-vue.js modules in nuxt.js

The below code in `nuxt.config.js` is pulling entire library (excluding css) but as mentioned above how to include required modules.

```
modules: [
  ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', { css: false }]
]
```

I referring docs here:

- https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/ please check for `Individual
  components and directives` section.
- https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules/#provide-plugins

Things described in above docs are passing over my head :) Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need bootstrap-vue/nuxt module if u want to cherry pick modules. You need to to either just import and use components as described in 'Individual components and directives
' section. Or create a plugin file, where u register them globally.

```
 plugins: [
    '@/plugins/mybs',
  ],
```

And inside plugin

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import bModal from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/modal/modal'
import bModalDirective from 'bootstrap-vue/es/directives/modal/modal'

Vue.component('b-modal', bModal);
Vue.directive('b-modal', bModalDirective);
```